# Bsearch function in C not working properly

Tags: c, bsearch

Basically I'm creating a program that will output the number if it is found in an given array or output -1 if not found. (Sorted Array.)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int cmp(const void*a,const void *b){
    if(*(int*)a-*(int*)b>0) return 1;
    if(*(int*)a-*(int*)b<0) return -1;
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    int n; scanf("%d",&n);
    int a[n];

    for(int i =0;i<n;i++) 
        scanf("%d",a+i);

    for(int i =0;i<n;i++){
        int *item;
        item = (int*)bsearch(&i,a,n,sizeof(int),cmp);
        if(item!=NULL) printf("%d ",i);
        else printf("-1 "); 
    }

    return 0;
}
```

INPUT : `10`

`-1 -1 6 1 9 3 2 -1 4 -1`

OUTPUT :
`-1 1 2 3 4 -1 6 -1 -1 9`

My OUTPUT :
`-1 -1 -1 3 4 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Comment: The array needs to be sorted. That's rather obvious (the __b__ in bsearch stands for binary) and the documentation mentions it.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli this problem could be solved that way.  It is not a duplicate of that question.

Comment: [binary search (...) is a search algorithm that finds the position of a target value within a **sorted array**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm)

Comment: BTW: `scanf("%d",a+i);`  is correct but you should rather write `scanf("%d", &a[i]);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_bsearch.htm

> The C library function void *bsearch(const void *key, const void *base, size_t nitems, size_t size, int (*compar)(const void *, const void *)) function searches an array of nitems objects, the initial member of which is pointed to by base, for a member that matches the object pointed to, by key. The size of each member of the array is specified by size.
>
> **The contents of the array should be in ascending sorted order** according to the comparison function referenced by compar.

The whole point of binary searching is that if the array has size `size` you start in position `size/2`. If this element is less than what you're looking for, then go to `size/2 + size/4`, and otherwise go to `size/2 - size/4`. If this approach should work, the array needs to be sorted.

Read more about binary searching here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm

And as mentioned in comments, `scanf("%d",a+i)` is correct, but `scanf("%d",&a[i])` is preferable.